# Twilio programmable chat javascript SDK not working

Tags: javascript, twilio

I was foing testing with twili chat demo js master.After sign in as guest i cant able to proceed like create channels and message.
the error i am getting in console is like this.

```
Navigated to http://localhost:81/twilio-chat-demo-js-master/public/644096210-idpiframe.js:24
GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc?action=listSessions&redirect…A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A81&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A81&app_package_name= 403 ()
Chat E: Failed to create session DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"><head><title>
Twilio | Login
</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" /><meta name="heartbeat"   content="twilio" />
<meta name="csrfToken"content="a6ce62734d9365bda924a1900f243fb21b8cd1e3bb6e32ff795f0b05214e817b"/><meta name="msvalidate.01" content="3D12095F1193FB34A99AEC3A6839D3C1" /><meta name="p:domain_verify" content="461cef7d1c33614f6741f1219779b382"/><meta property="twitter:account_id" content="15936194" /><link href="https://plus.google.com/102140742001641246827" rel="publisher" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/console/bundles/favicons/img/Twilio_64.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/console/bundles/favicons/img/Twilio_57.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/console/bundles/favicons/img/Twilio_72.png" /><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/console/bundles/favicons/img/Twilio_114.png" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//static1.twilio.com/bundles/console-core.css?5aee3970b1cf2a0ea543047650ae9f2a"/><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//static1.twilio.com/bundles/console-partners.css?7c1ee82bf67108cf982c35489aae06cb"/><script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Looks like there is something going on with Google OAuth that's returning a 403 there. Can you share a bit more of your code and what you've been testing that caused this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem for the error message above is..the get token response giving full of text data.Actually it should give only token in response. so i used [rest api to get the token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens) .Then its worked fine for me.